# React Native Offline mode with AsyncStorage not parsing array of items properly

Tags: react-native, offline, asyncstorage

I am developing the offline mode for my app using AsyncStorage. Somehow, API calls are made super fine when online, rendering an array of three objects. But once I switch to offline mode, the data parsed returns three times the same object, instead of three different ones as it would do online. I console.logged what is stored, nothing wrong my 3 objects are stored properly. I also console.logged my parsed data, and here I indeed log 3 times the same object. I can't figure out what in my code could be missing or be wrong.

```
export async function workflowBuilding(currentItem: string) {
  try {
    const apiURL = `${Config.API_URL}obj/Building?constraints=[{"key":"_id","constraint_type":"equals","value":"${currentItem}"}]`;

    // Check internet connection
    const isConnected = await NetInfo.fetch().then(state => state.isConnected);

    if (isConnected) {
      // If there's an internet connection, fetch data from the API
      const responseFetch = await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Config.API_KEY}`,
        },
      });

      const responseData = await responseFetch.json();

      // Store the response data in AsyncStorage
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'workflowBuildingData',
        JSON.stringify(responseData),
      );

      console.warn(
        '_____________________________________',
        responseData,
      );
      return responseData;
    } else {
      // If there's no internet connection, fetch data from AsyncStorage
      const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('workflowBuildingData');

      if (storedData) {
        console.log('_____________________________________', storedData);
        return JSON.parse(storedData);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur dans auth.tsx: function workflowBuilding', error);
  }
}
```

When online, here is the result in the console:
[image: console.log]

Then as I go offline, here is the result in the console:
[image: console.log]

I have done some research and so far I really can't find anything to help me... Here is the screen where it is being called:

```
  const displayingBuilding = useCallback(async () => {
    if (user?.kind === 'Resident') {
      const idBuildings = user.Building;
      const infosBuilding = await Promise.all(
        idBuildings.map(async currentItem => {
          try {
            const responseBuilding = await workflowBuilding(currentItem);
            const {
              response: {
                results: [buildingReturn],
              },
            } = responseBuilding;
            return buildingReturn;
          } catch (e) {
            if ((e as Error).message === 'Network request failed') {
              Alert.alert(
                'Pas de connexion internet',
                'Veuillez activer votre réseau internet',
              );
            }
          }
        }),
      );
      const arrayCodeBuildingList = infosBuilding.map(currentItem => ({
        nom: currentItem.Nom_Building,
        codeAccessPermanent: currentItem.Access_Permanent,
        codeAccessTemporary: currentItem.Access_Temporaire,
        entreprise: currentItem.Company,
        codePostal: currentItem.CP_Building,
        rue: currentItem.Rue_Building,
        ville: currentItem.Ville_Building,
        id: currentItem._id,
        UIID: currentItem.UUID_Device,
      }));
      setDataBuilding(arrayCodeBuildingList);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Hope someone will know :)

Comment: From what I understand, `workflowBuilding` doesn't get 3 objects, `workflowBuilding` is called 3 times, right ?

Comment: Yes it does indeed, I am mapping at some point in my screen's code:  idBuildings.map(async currentItem => {
          try {
            const responseBuilding = await workflowBuilding(currentItem);
            const {
              response: {
                results: [buildingReturn],
              },
            } = responseBuilding;
            return buildingReturn;

Comment: Please add the console logs as text and not as an image.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because AsyncStorage is a key/value based system. Think of it like an object. When you write `x = { a: 1 }; x.a = 2; console.log(x.a);` you get `2`, not `[1,2]`. When you `setItem`, you replace the value stored at that key. If you want to keep track of past values, you'll need to write that part yourself.

Comment: Wow yes Abe, what you're saying is now making sense in my head. I basically replace the value of my AsyncStorage key for each item mapped in the array. With this in mind I will try to find a workaround. If you have any suggestions I take it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: since the .map method was executing workflowBuilding() for each item returned, which here was 3 times, the value stored in AsyncStorage for the key workflowBuildingData was updated 3 times. Wrong. That's why instead of getting an array of three objects returned later in the code, I was getting three times the last object returned. So I modified the code, and instead of storing my data directly in the workflowBuilding() function, I do it now after this .map() returned its data. Here is the new code:

```
export async function workflowBuilding(currentItem: string) {
  const responseFetch = await fetch(
    //POST Request to Bubble Backend
    `${Config.API_URL}obj/Building?constraints=[{"key":"_id","constraint_type":"equals","value":"${currentItem}"}]`, //pour l'instant la personne qui se connecte est la même
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Config.API_KEY}`,
      },
    },
  );
  return await responseFetch.json();
}
```

and the code where I store the data for offline use:

```
  const displayingBuilding = useCallback(async () => {
    if (user?.kind === 'Resident') {
      let arrayCodeBuildingList:
        | string
        | any[]
        | ((
            prevState: Buildings[] | null | undefined,
          ) => Buildings[] | null | undefined)
        | null
        | undefined = [];

      try {
        const idBuildings = user.Building;
        const infosBuilding = await Promise.all(
          idBuildings.map(async currentItem => {
            try {
              const responseBuilding = await workflowBuilding(currentItem);
              const buildingReturn = responseBuilding.response.results[0];
              return buildingReturn;
            } catch (e) {
              if (e.message === 'Network request failed') {
                // If network request failed, get data from storage
                const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('buildingData');
                if (storedData) {
                  console.log('new stored data_______', storedData);
                  // Data was found in storage? parse and use it
                  const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
                  arrayCodeBuildingList = parsedData;
                } else {
                  Alert.alert(
                    'Pas de connexion internet',
                    'Veuillez activer votre réseau internet',
                  );
                }
              }
            }
          }),
        );

        if (arrayCodeBuildingList.length === 0) {
          arrayCodeBuildingList = infosBuilding.map(currentItem => ({
            nom: currentItem.Nom_Building,
            codeAccessPermanent: currentItem.Access_Permanent,
            codeAccessTemporary: currentItem.Access_Temporaire,
            entreprise: currentItem.Company,
            codePostal: currentItem.CP_Building,
            rue: currentItem.Rue_Building,
            ville: currentItem.Ville_Building,
            id: currentItem._id,
            UIID: currentItem.UUID_Device,
          }));
        }

        // Save to AsyncStorage for offline mode, here rather than in auth.tsx to avoid bug caused by the .map() above
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'buildingData',
          JSON.stringify(arrayCodeBuildingList),
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }

      // Update state with the data returned before
      setDataBuilding(arrayCodeBuildingList);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Tadaam :) Hope it will help someone in the future and thanks @Abe and
@OneQ for checking it and pointing out the issue!